# Brother HL-2240 Printer: Job Completed, but No Actual Printing

Tags: usb, printing

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1, and suddenly all my print jobs got stuck on pending.  I was going to try re-adding the printer through the Printer GUI, but when I removed it does not give me the option to add it again.  It now asks for the devices URI.

Typing in lsusb in terminal seems to show that it's recognized.

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04f9:0045 Brother Industries, Ltd 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:0833 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:0939 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 008 Device 002: ID 148f:5372 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5372 Wireless Adapter
    Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any ideas of how I should troubleshoot this?

UPDATE:  So, I had to reinstall all the drivers again and now it's recognized.  But now it says job completed, yet it prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this;   first this will cost you about 480MB of space;  (if running off USB like I am, you may not be thrilled);

the DEB driver files on the brother page did not work for me;  Jet Direct, CUPS admin, and IPP setups did not work; GnuPrint Drivers did not work for me.  GUI server setting (allowing print sharing etc) did not work. 
Editing the .etc --> SMB --> smb.config file,  did not completely work for me.

Don't waste your time there.

***You must use the .GZ package installer provided on the Brother site.

You must open terminal and CD (Change directory) to where you have downloaded the file. Then follow the command lines listed on the brother page.
The Brother command lines do the following 2 steps: 
1.  Gunzip (unzip) the package ;
2.  Run the installer via 'Sudo Bash';

**It helps to know the Full Printer Name, URL, or IP address of the printer before you begin but not necessary.  The installer wizard will ask you questions,  I chose to select the 'Auto' install options; to let the installer decide as much as possible.